# Javascript Showing Blank Grey Layer

Tags: javascript, html

Guys my site - http://techinger.com/ When I Click on Login Button It Shows Grey Error Page Instead Of Login Box. I already have Login Box Placed After javascript Code.

```html
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="openStaticPopup()">Login</a>
```

Above is Login Button And Below is Login Button Code That i Need To Show Above grey Layer

```html
<div id="loginform" class="logarea">
    <div class="popuplog">
        <div class="popup-head">
            Authorization
            <a class="popup-close" href="javascript:;" onclick="$.closePopupLayer('loginPopup')" title="Close"> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="popupcol">
  <form method="post" action="">
     <ul class="reset">
      <li class="edge">
                            <label for="login_name"><p>Username:</p></label>
                            <input class="f_input" type="text" name="login_name" id="login_name" />
                        </li>
      <li class="edge">
                            <label for="login_password"><p>Password (<a href="http://techinger.com/index.php?do=lostpassword">Forgot?</a>):</p></label>
                            <input class="f_input" type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" />
      </li>
      <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="login_not_save" id="login_not_save" value="1"/><label for="login_not_save">&nbsp;Third party computer</label>
      </li><br />
      <li class="lfield lfchek"><div class="sociallogin">
       
       
       
       
       
       
      </div>
      </li>
      <br />
                        <div align="center"><li><button class="poll-submit" onclick="submit();" type="submit" title="Login"><span>Login</span></button></li></div>
     </ul>
            <input name="login" type="hidden" id="login" value="submit" />
   </form>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Please Tell Me Where Code or Line Is missing That i Can Show Login Modal there?

Comment: please isolate the problematic part of the code and post it in your question. no one is going to go through all the scripts on your website to find out why your website isnt working.

Comment: @Banana I have not coded this template manually so i dont know where is problem :(

Comment: you should nevertheless go through all the code yourself first. show some effort from your side and try solving the issue on your own, and if you get stuck then post your attempts in your question and we will be happy to help.

Comment: @Banana I am posting this because i am stuck at this problem

Comment: Use the dev tools that come with your browser. If you right click and `inspect element` then select `console` you will see your javascript error as described by Banana below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `popups.js` file you have a line that crashes the code:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7) {
```

this line calls `$.browser` which is deprecated since jQuery 1.9

you have 2 options:

- remove this line and ignore internet explorer < 7
- link jQuery migrate that will restore the deprecated functions:
  include the following line right after your link to jQuery:
  `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>`

source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Answer (score -1):

You have in your CSS:

```
.logarea{
   display: none;
}
```

so you can't see it.

Comment: Can You Please Tell me What Do Edit Here?

Comment: thats not how jquery popups work, and changing the logarea display attribute will only mess up the page.

Comment: @Banana Guys is there any solution for this?